# NullPointerException in "onActivityResult" of In-App-Billing V3 Library

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm having a small issue with a NullPointerException in my app after completing a test purchase through the library In App Billing V3.

I can successfully call the test purchase byclicking the specific menuItem just fine. My issue is that after the test purchase window closes, instead of  getting information on whether the item was already purchased, or any other info in logcat, it throws me an NPE error, as I will paste below:

```
Error in handleActivityResult
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
        at com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.BillingProcessor.handleActivityResult(BillingProcessor.java:932)
        at com.example.android.visitri.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:806)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6931)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4090)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1529)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Does my setup of the library's functions for In-App Billing seem proper otherwise? Am I maybe getting this NPE error to throw because I'm just using a test purchase or is something with my setup wrong?

You can find onActivityResult (where the error originates) near the bottom of the code pasted below.

```
BillingProcessor bp;

---

bp = BillingProcessor.newBillingProcessor(this, null, this);
bp.initialize();

---

if (i == R.id.more_menu) {
            View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.more_menu);
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView);
            // Inflate the menu from xml
            popup.inflate(R.menu.popup_more_menu);
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.menu_remove_ads:
                            boolean isAvailable =
                                    BillingProcessor.isIabServiceAvailable(MainActivity.this);
                            // If the Play Store isn't installed on the phone (if it's a certain
                            // Chinese phone, older phone, or otherwise), don't run the purchase.
                            if (!isAvailable) {
                                return true;
                            }
                            // Checks to see if Billing is supported,
                            // and if it is, run the purchase.
                            boolean isOneTimePurchaseSupported = bp.isOneTimePurchaseSupported();
                            if (isOneTimePurchaseSupported) {
                                bp.purchase(MainActivity.this, "android.test.canceled");
                            }
                            return true;
                    }
                }
            });

---

@Override
    public void onBillingInitialized() {
        /*
         * Called when BillingProcessor was initialized and it's ready to purchase
         */
    }

    @Override
    public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String productId, @Nullable TransactionDetails details) {
        /*
         * Called when requested PRODUCT ID was successfully purchased
         */
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingError(int errorCode, @Nullable Throwable error) {
        /*
         * Called when some error occurred. See Constants class for more details
         *
         * Note - this includes handling the case where the user canceled the buy dialog:
         * errorCode = Constants.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_USER_CANCELED
         */
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
        /*
         * Called when purchase history was restored and the list of all owned PRODUCT ID's
         * was loaded from Google Play
         */
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (bp != null) {
            bp.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Thanks so much for any advice or input you might have for me! :)

Comment: in your code, where are you doing String.length() ?

Comment: Hello  Gastón, I assume String.length() is being called by the BillingProcessor class in onActivityResult, where it is trying to create an order summary for me, or notify me if the item has already been purchased - but instead, it throws the NPE I pasted above. I'm just confused why "bp", which is properly initialized and assigned, is seen as a null object reference after the in-app purchase window closes.